# NSUndoManager not keeping the stack with redo/undo for an iPhone app for UnDo/Redo drawings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, undo, nsundomanager, redo

I am building an iPhone app with Objective C. In my app, I am drawing the strokes on image and want to implement the undo and redo functionalities.

I have used `NSUndoManager` for this. With this I am able to undo my drawing at one level down, but my requirement is to undo the drawing at its lowest possible level (or at least minimum 10 level down). I had already set the `setLevelsOfUndo` to 10 but it does not work.

I'm using the following code:

```
- (void)UnDoImage1:(UIImage*)image
{
    if (capturedImage.image != image)
    {
        [self.managedObjectContext.undoManager undo];
        [[self.managedObjectContext.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] UnDoImage1:capturedImage.image];
        [capturedImage release];
        capturedImage.image = [image retain];
    }
}
```

Please let me know where I am incorrect. I have already Googled for this for a long time but did not find the exact cause of failure of the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that you can use `prepareWithInvocationTarget:` with an object as a Parameter. Its not going to Keep a copy of  `capturedImage.image` around for the Undo/Redo Stack. So Since you are releasing it and setting it to the new image, the reference to the original is lost and you will just be calling UnDoImage1: with the current `capturedImage.image`

If thats the only thing you are looking to undo/redo, then I would look at `registerUndoWithTarget:selector:object:` it will hold onto a reference of `capturedImage.image`.

Scott<-